# What is wrong with my combinatorics method?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I want to select a team of $7$ from a pool of $10$ from $A$, $8$ from $B$ and $5$ from $C$. However, I want to make sure that I have at least one from each group.

My idea was to do the following $$10 \times 8 \times 5 \times \binom{20}{4}$$

the $10$, $8$ and $5$ are to choose the one member from each team, who is 'guaranteed' a spot. The $\binom{20}{4}$ is to choose the remaining $4$ team members from the remaining pool of $20$ people.

The problem is that this value is larger than $\binom{23}{7}$, which should be the largest possible value.

Comment: Multiple counting. If Alicia and Beti are group A, then you have counted Alicia chosen "first", with Beti among the $4$ chosen "later" as different from Beti first, and Alicia later.  I suggest using Inclusion/Exclusion, $\binom{23}{7}$ minus the number of bad teams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may have to use inclusion / exclusion for this one. Then you get

$${23\choose 7}-\left({13\choose 7}+{15\choose 7}+{18\choose 7}\right)+\left({{10\choose 7}+{8\choose 7}+0}\right)=205\ 310.$$

So the middle terms are the cases where no one is from A, B, or C respectively, and the rightmost terms are the cases where no one is from B or C, A or C, or A or B respectively.